# Java 8 reduce a map based on condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map like this which is a collection of start dates as keys and an object as value.

```
"periodsByStartDate": {
        "2020-10-12": {
            "value1": 1E+2,
            "value2": 1.63,
            "endDate": "2020-10-18"
        },
        "2020-10-05": {
            "value1": 1E+2,
            "value2": 1.63,
            "endDate": "2020-10-11"
        },
        "2020-10-19": {
            "value1": 1E+2,
            "value2": 1.63,
            "endDate": "2020-10-25"
        }
}
```

Is there a Java 8 way we can use to make it like below so that we roll up if the value1 and value2 of the objects are same and the resulting entry in the map should have the end date of last object that we add up.

```
"periodsByStartDate": {
            "2020-10-05": {
                "value1": 1E+2,
                "value2": 1.63,
                "endDate": "2020-10-25"
            }        
    }
```

Comment: what about the key for the result, how did `2020-10-05` become one? what schema does these follow in Java currently? where is your attempt to the problem?

Comment: Yes, there is a Java 8 way. Now read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: @Naman `2020-10-05` became the start date, because the input is 3 date ranges `2020-10-05` to `2020-10-11`, `2020-10-12` to `2020-10-18`, and `2020-10-19` to `2020-10-25`, and since the 2 value fields are the same in all 3, and the date ranges are consecutive, they are merged into a single date range of `2020-10-05` to `2020-10-25`.